# sql looking in two colums in different tables for a value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How can I search for a value e. g. e-mail address in several tables with different columns? Or optimize my query?

My Example

```
$email = 'some_email@example.com';

$email = "SELECT a.email_one, a.email_two,b.email_three 
FROM first_table AS a, second_table AS b 
WHERE a.email_one = $email OR b.email_two = $email";
```

Thank you!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Perhaps `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Sossy, I corrected my code. With UNION I need to have the same number of columns. My query it is different.

Comment: you should use inner join and equals all email columns in `ON` condition. please check my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i have corrected my code it now a little bit different. I should check three colums.

Answer (score 1):

If it can appear in two tables but no related data between the two tables just use `UNION` between queries from two tables

```
SELECT a.email, 'from-first-table' from first_table a where ...
UNION 
SELECT b.email, 'from-second-table' from second_table b where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT a.email_one, b.email_two 
FROM first_table AS a inner join second_table AS b 
ON a.email_one=b.email_two and a.email_one='".$email."'`

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always a bad schema design to splay an array (of emails, in your case) across columns.  Instead, use multiple rows in an extra table:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM Main
    JOIN Emails  USING(user_id)
    WHERE Emails.email = '$email';

Emails:  INDEX(email, user_id)
```

Very efficient; allows 0, 1, 2, or more than 2 emails per user.